# Function creates a folder but do not cd into the folder if it exists

Tags: command-line, zsh

Following is the function I have added in the **.zshrc** configuration file to create a Notes folder if it does not exist and if the folder exists it has to cd to that folder.

```shell
function mnotes(){
   if [ ! -d ~/Desktop/Notes ];then
      mkdir ~/Desktop/Notes
   else
      cd ~/Desktop/Notes
   fi
}
```

I have set an alias as  follows:

```shell
alias notes=mnotes
```

After sourcing the .zshrc file. and typing the command notes, it will create the notes folder, but doesnt not cd into it if the folder exists.
[Error Image while running the script when the folder is present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEpZ6.png)

Comment: The error message appears to refer to `~/Desktop/Projects` not `~/Desktop/Notes` - are you sure the code you are showing us is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you meant to do something like this (make the dir AND execute the cd. Yours does either the "mkdir" or the "cd" due to the else).

My version would be this:

```
function mnotes(){
   mkdir -p ~/Desktop/Notes/ && cd ~/Desktop/Notes/   
}
```

Comment: I got the solution, I created a separate shell script and added the code. In the .zshrc file I did the following
`alias notes= "cd ~/scripts && ./notes.sh && source notes.sh"`
sourcing the script file made it work.

Comment: If the directory creation fails because the directory already exists, then the cd command would not be executed because of the `&&`. Shouldn't you then just have a `; ` separating the commands? Anyway, this is already accepted, so it will probably work as such.

Comment: @vanadium the -p option in mkdir will prevent that.

Comment: @Jean-Marie Thanks, it was actually easy to test this for myself.